# IE7 and Javascript "An Error as occurred" pop-up

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer-7

I am working with a Rails 3.1 app that is having the hardest time in IE7. I keep getting the "An error has occurred in the script on this page" everytime I click into an input field. I have the IE debugbar but in Rails the assets are compressed so you can't really debug the issue at hand.

As anyone else ran into this issue and if so, how did you fix it?

**Edit**

Here is where its "failing" in IE7 (jquery.js file)

```
attr: function( elem, name, value, pass ) {
    var ret, hooks, notxml,
        nType = elem.nodeType;

    // don't get/set attributes on text, comment and attribute nodes
    if ( !elem || nType === 3 || nType === 8 || nType === 2 ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( pass && jQuery.isFunction( jQuery.fn[ name ] ) ) {
        return jQuery( elem )[ name ]( value );
    }

    // Fallback to prop when attributes are not supported
    if ( typeof elem.getAttribute === "undefined" ) {
        return jQuery.prop( elem, name, value );
    }

    notxml = nType !== 1 || !jQuery.isXMLDoc( elem );

    // All attributes are lowercase
    // Grab necessary hook if one is defined
    if ( notxml ) {
        name = name.toLowerCase();
        hooks = jQuery.attrHooks[ name ] || ( rboolean.test( name ) ? boolHook : nodeHook );
    }

    if ( value !== undefined ) {

        if ( value === null ) {
            jQuery.removeAttr( elem, name );
            return;

        } else if ( hooks && "set" in hooks && notxml && (ret = hooks.set( elem, value, name )) !== undefined ) {
            return ret;

        } else {
            elem.setAttribute( name, "" + value );
            return value;
        }

    } else if ( hooks && "get" in hooks && notxml && (ret = hooks.get( elem, name )) !== null ) {
        return ret;

    } else {
                    // FAILING HERE WITH THIS LINE
        ret = elem.getAttribute( name );

        // Non-existent attributes return null, we normalize to undefined
        return ret === null ?
            undefined :
            ret;
    }
},
```

Im not sure why this is failing, but it is.

Comment: I'd figure out how to serve the assets unminified and unobfuscated for development purposes.

Comment: I did a quick google search for `ret = elem.getAttribute( name );` and it seems like it might be because you are trying to access a DOM property (e.g. `checked`) by using `attr` instead of `prop`. Does that seem like it might be it?

Comment: that's possible... I am trying to traverse through each of the jQuery libraries and see if I can locate it. Its weird, cause this error is occurring wherever I click on the page

Comment: Ok, I think I am nailed it down to be an issue with the jquery_ujs (Rails.js) file included with the application

Answer (score 1):

Run it in development mode and don't compress the javascript files so you can actually debug it.